# Try Catch assigning value issue

Tags: java, try-catch

When i input int first program check and assign value but not print, next int I input it does print but first value entered. If value is string, asks again but doesn`t assign the value to number. How can i solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 0;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            number = kb.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not a number!");
            kb.nextLine();

        }

    } while (!kb.hasNextInt());
    System.out.println(number);

}
```

output

```
Enter a number: ab
Not a number!
5
Number: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't mix nextLine and nextAnything else. If you want to read entire lines, use `.next()`, and update your scanner's delimiter: `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` - Doing it your way means, if the user uses the largest key on your keyboard, your app breaks.
2. You should probably put this in a utility method.
3. Don't use `.hasNextInt()` in your while condition. It returns false if the user enters a non-number. Just make that while true, and break out of the loop if the input is correct. Note that `kb.hasNextInt` will freeze (wait) until the user enters something. After all, as long as the user has not entered another token, how could scanner possibly tell you if it's an int or not?

Comment: If you're not going to use the nextXXX methods, it might be better to just use a BufferedReader#readLine() instead.. I've never liked Scanner.